# ffmpeg - Merge back frames to a video with the same encoding

Tags: image-processing, ffmpeg

I have a video encoded using H264 at 23.98 fps, for a duration of 00:00:06.42.

I extracted the frames from that video, and then I processed those images one-by-one. Now I want to put them back together as a video, but I want to be the same as the source video (same duration, same audio, etc).

Whatever I tried gives something different. The duration is always greater (around 00:00:06.59), the audio seems to be up to the end of the video (as expected), but the frame are not encoded properly, and they seems to freeze at the end and the audio continue.

The one that look almost the same except the freeze at the end look like this:

```
ffmpeg -i input.mov \
       -pattern_type glob -i 'result_*.tif' 
       -map 1 -map 0:a \
       -map_metadata 0 \
       -map_metadata:s:v 0:s:v \
       -map_metadata:s:a 0:s:a \
       output.mov
```

Where I use the metadata and the audio from the input video, and use the frames from my second input.

**EDIT:** As suggested here the details of the source video.

```
ffmpeg version 2.8.15 Copyright (c) 2000-2018 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 4.8.5 (GCC) 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-28)
  configuration: --prefix=/usr --bindir=/usr/bin --datadir=/usr/share/ffmpeg --incdir=/usr/include/ffmpeg --libdir=/usr/lib64 --mandir=/usr/share/man --arch=x86_64 --optflags='-O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector-strong --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -grecord-gcc-switches -m64 -mtune=generic' --extra-ldflags='-Wl,-z,relro ' --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-version3 --enable-bzlib --disable-crystalhd --enable-gnutls --enable-ladspa --enable-libass --enable-libcdio --enable-libdc1394 --disable-indev=jack --enable-libfreetype --enable-libgsm --enable-libmp3lame --enable-openal --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopus --enable-libpulse --enable-libschroedinger --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libtheora --enable-libvorbis --enable-libv4l2 --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxvid --enable-x11grab --enable-avfilter --enable-avresample --enable-postproc --enable-pthreads --disable-static --enable-shared --enable-gpl --disable-debug --disable-stripping --shlibdir=/usr/lib64 --enable-runtime-cpudetect
  libavutil      54. 31.100 / 54. 31.100
  libavcodec     56. 60.100 / 56. 60.100
  libavformat    56. 40.101 / 56. 40.101
  libavdevice    56.  4.100 / 56.  4.100
  libavfilter     5. 40.101 /  5. 40.101
  libavresample   2.  1.  0 /  2.  1.  0
  libswscale      3.  1.101 /  3.  1.101
  libswresample   1.  2.101 /  1.  2.101
  libpostproc    53.  3.100 / 53.  3.100
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'Transparent.mov':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : qt
    minor_version   : 0
    compatible_brands: qt
    creation_time   : 2019-09-17 22:06:44
  Duration: 00:00:06.42, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 47798 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(und): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 113 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2019-09-17 22:06:44
      handler_name    : Core Media Data Handler
    Stream #0:1(und): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p(tv, bt709), 3840x2160 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 47541 kb/s, 23.98 fps, 23.98 tbr, 24k tbn, 48k tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2019-09-17 22:06:44
      handler_name    : Core Media Data Handler
      encoder         : H.264
      timecode        : 00:00:00:00
    Stream #0:2(und): Data: none (tmcd / 0x64636D74), 0 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2019-09-17 22:06:44
      handler_name    : Core Media Data Handler
      timecode        : 00:00:00:00
At least one output file must be specified
```

Comment: Show info about the original video. Show the complete output of `ffmpeg -i input.mov`

Comment: @llogan I added the info of my video

Comment: 2.8.15 is ancient. I recommend using something modern. [Download](https://johnvansickle.com/ffmpeg/) or [compile](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/CompilationGuide/Centos).

Comment: 2.8.15 is the latest available on CentOS 7 right now. But I could check to compile from latest or something like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your input has a frame rate of 24000/1001, but the default frame rate for the [image demuxer](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-formats.html#image2-1) is 25. Add the `-framerate` input option:

```
ffmpeg -i input.mov \
       -framerate 24000/1001 -pattern_type glob -i 'result_*.tif' \
       -map 1 -map 0:a \
       -map_metadata 0 \
       -map_metadata:s:v 0:s:v \
       -map_metadata:s:a 0:s:a \
       output.mov
```

Comment: Using this, the video still ends up at `00:00:06.49` instead of `00:00:06.42`, which the final frame look to freeze while the audio continue a bit. Im updating ffmpeg for now, and I will retry.

Comment: Using `N-50037-g4ba45a95df-static`, the time reach `00:00:06.44`, not 42, but much nearer, and it impossible to see the difference/freeze now.